# Code to forward browser if user is not logged in (checking if session variable isset) is not firing

Tags: php, session, redirect, logout, isset

I am trying to set all of my pages to forward to the login screen if the user is not logged in using session data, however it is not working. When a user clicks the links it just continues to the new link as opposed to being forwarded to the login page. I know the session data is cleared so that is not the issue. 
Here's the relevant Code:

Page Headers:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['answer']))
    {
        header('Location: /?login');
        exit;
    }?>
```

Login Session Declaration:

```
 $answer = mssql_fetch_array($res);
    $_SESSION['answer']=$answer[0];
```

Logout:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
if(!isset($_SESSION['answer']))
{
    header('Location: /?login');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response on how to do this on every other page:

I use a required at the beginning of every secured php page on my site.  I call it "auth.php".  If the user is not logged in(check via session variable), the auth.php re-directs them to the login page.

If you have a header, this is a great place to put it (if it's only included in the secured section, which mine is).

My logout page destroys the session and sends them to the login page.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful, but do you see where in my code mine is not working?

Comment: @Christopher: `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: I would try what zerkms said and redirect unconditionally.  Remove the isset on your logout page.

Comment: @Mikecito Redirect unconditionally on every page? That would make it so regardless of if I was logged in I would be redirected to login. That is quite the oppisite of what I want.

Comment: I just did it the long way -.- still would love to know a more efficient way to do this though.

Comment: Oh I understand.  You would include the isset on your auth.php... I meant just remove it from your logout page.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

[session_destroy](https://www.php.net/session_destroy) doesn't unset any global variables.

If you need to redirect unconditionally right after session destroy - just remove `isset`, you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you! Any tips for the redirect on every other page?

Comment: @Christopher: I cannot get the question :-(

Comment: I am trying to cause a redirect on every page where the Session !isset